# Anyway to write spark partitions into different sub-paths?

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

When I use

> df.repartition(100).write.mode('overwrite').json(output_path)

Spark will write 100 json files under the same path specified by 'output_path'. **Is it possible to write partitions into different sub-directories**? For example, the first 10 partitions written into 'output_path/01/', and the second 10 partitions written into 'output_path/02', and so on?

It is not restricted to this scheme. I just need to avoid writing all output data into the same path; I need to partition the dataframe and write them into different subfolders.

---

The motivation for this question is that, I am using AWS s3, and whenever I write all data under the same path, it gives me a 'SLOW DOWN' error. I am informed that the writing speed limit is "prefix based", that is, if I write all data into

s3://someurl/

Then I will get a SLOW DOWN error. Instead, I need to write some data into s3://someurl/01/, and some into s3://someurl/02/, and s3://someurl/03/, ... I need help how to achieve this.

---

Of course, one way to solve this is to use `where` to manually separate data; but I hope there is some build-in mechanism to more elegantly solve this. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could add a dummy partition column like

```py
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
df = df.withColumn("dummy", F.floor(F.rand() * 10))
df.write.partitionBy("dummy").mode('overwrite').json(output_path)
```

This will generate the following paths:

```
s3://someurl/dummy=0/
s3://someurl/dummy=1/
s3://someurl/dummy=2/
...
```

On the downside you'll have an extra column when reading